# SharePoint 2013 dragdrop.js throws refused to set unsafe header content-length error

Tags: drag-and-drop, sharepoint-2013, document-library

I have a document library where I have put code in content editor web part. The issue is, when I drag and drop any document in this library, I am getting below error in browser console:

> refused to set unsafe header content-length error

This issue is generated in SharePoint 'dragdrop.js' file and it stops all the script execution on the page. So my function is not firing. What should I do  to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the latest update may have caused this problem, as I never had this problem before in the past either. No settings in the Developer panel nor the preferences screen seem to help with this.

*Update: Check patches on Sharepoint 2013 - we recently had patches done on ours which can cause different behaviours in browsers to surface (ours seemed to have affected Safari). We haven't had any modifications/codes done preceding the dragdrop.js call but it also fails. Still looking for solutions.

Comment: We are facing this issue in chrome (Version 56.0.2924.87). We are not using safari.

Comment: Ah ok... Tried other browsers yet? Same problem?

Comment: How much have you patched Sharepoint 2013, up to the latest patches/fixes?

Comment: December 2014 CU.

Comment: Hmm it appears our installation wasn't patched, it's still at/on SP1 with maybe a hotfix here or there... sorry I cannot be of any help. Though, I noticed there are still heaps of patches beyond December 2014...

Comment: Actually, while I am here, I may as well ask, by any chance you applied a different jquery file... or some other library similar --- have you tried using a different version, perhaps?? (hopeful)

Comment: we were using jquery 1.8.2 first. But as you suggest, I find blog some where and changed our version to 2.0 now. But, still we are having same issue.